# Amazon MWS Report API always change the request reports to status 'CANCELLED'

Tags: reporting-services, amazon-mws

I want to use the Amazon MWS Report API and I am using this http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_Overview.html. 
I create successfully Request report, but when I check the report with GetReportRequestList call my request has 'CANCELLED' status.

Is there a way to find why the report request are cancelled?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer might be here: [Do not request FBA reports more frequently than they are generated](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/fba_guide/FBAGuide_DoNotRequestFBAReports.html)

The same thing happened to me years ago and it was because I was testing with the scratchpad and sending too many requests in a short amount of time.